# Only one element in array of file paths working - C

Tags: c, arrays, file, path

I am trying to opening files from 2 different file paths but I seem to only be able to open them from one at a time. In the load_data function path[0] opens files in the first path and when I change it to path[1] it opens files in the second path. How can I get it to open both?

```
    char *paths[] = {"C:\\transactions\\confirmed\\", "C:\\transactions\\pending\\"};
    char *suffix = "MCW.txt";
    char * filenames[9] = {
    //Confirmed:
    "1519511094", "1519515094", "1519609024", "1519611094", "1519811094", 

    //Pending
    "1520021094", "1520111094", "1520121094", "1520122094"
    };

    void load_data(void)
    {
    int i;
    char FullPath[100];
    FILE *TransFile;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    {
    sprintf(FullPath, "%s%s%s", paths[0], filenames[i], suffix);
    printf("Attempt Opening File number %d File name %s\n", i, FullPath);
    TransFile = fopen(FullPath, "r");

    if (TransFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        //continue;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Success opening!\n");
        fclose(TransFile);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Use 2 `FILE *` handles, not just one.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: use a inner loop from 0 to 1 to open `paths[j]` and store in `Transfile[j]`, with `FILE *Transfile[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entierly clear as for what you wish to achive or what is your file-system structure you wish to operate on

but it seems that you should either create another file descriptor to work with or create an inner loop handling file opertions

the second proposal i wrote allows you to keep all file descriptors, (if i understand correctly 18 in total (9 files in each directory) - I'm not sure i understood you fully but hopefully this will give you some kind of sense on what should be done.

It's not a nice solution but it can be adapted to fit your needs

```
FILE *TransFileConfirmed;
FILE *TransFilePending;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
{
sprintf(FullPath, "%s%s%s", paths[0], filenames[i], suffix);
printf("Attempt Opening File number %d File name %s\n", i, FullPath);
TransFileConfirmed = fopen(FullPath, "r");

sprintf(FullPath, "%s%s%s", paths[1], filenames[i], suffix);
printf("Attempt Opening File number %d File name %s\n", i, FullPath);
TransFilePending = fopen(FullPath, "r");

if ( !TransFileConfirmed ||  !TransFilePending)
{
    printf("Error!\n");
    //continue;
}
else
{
    printf("Success opening!\n");
    fclose(TransFilePending);
    fclose(TransFileConfirmed);
}
```

or

```
FILE *Trans[9 * 2];
int j;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
       sprintf(FullPath, "%s%s%s", paths[j], filenames[i], suffix);
       printf("Attempt Opening File number %d File name %s\n", i, FullPath);
       Trans[j*i + i] = fopen(FullPath, "r");

       if ( !Trans[j*i + i] )
       {
            printf("Error!\n");
           //continue;
       }
       else
       {
            printf("Success opening!\n");
            fclose(Trans[j*i + i]);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry if I did not explain very well but I am trying to open files from two different directories: C:\transactions\confirmed and C:\transactions\pending. There are 5 files in one and 4 in the other. I have tried your solutions above and it seems to scan both directories and open confirmed files but give and error for pending files then scans them all again and gives an error for confirmed files but opens pending.

Comment: Output:

Attempt Opening File number 0 File name C:\transactions\confirmed\1519511094MCW.txt
Success opening!
Attempt Opening File number 0 File name C:\transactions\pending\1519511094MCW.txt
Error!
Attempt Opening File number 1 File name C:\transactions\confirmed\1519515094MCW.txt
Success opening!
Attempt Opening File number 1 File name C:\transactions\pending\1519515094MCW.txt
Error!
Attempt Opening File number 2 File name C:\transactions\confirmed\1519609024MCW.txt
Success opening!
Attempt Opening File number 2 File name C:\transactions\pending\1519609024MCW.txt
Error!

etc..

Comment: in your code you hold all the files in the same array - `filenames`. my solution assumes that all 9 files exist in both directories... if that is not the case consider seperatinf `filenames` to `filenamesConf` and `filenamesPend` and then seperate the two open sequences...

Comment: That does solve the problem. Seems like more code that it should be for this but it works so thank you for your help!